# Read first number of user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a bit of help. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I need code that checks the first number of user input. For example I enter the numbers `34566` and it looks at the first number and prints 'he' or 'she'.

Maybe some one can give me some advice how to solve it.

```
print("Sisesta isikukood")
isikukood[0] = int(input())

if (isikukood[0] == 1 or isikukood[0]== 3 or isikukood[0]== 5):
    print("He")
else:
    if isikukood[0] == 2 or isikukood[0]== 4 or isikukood[0] == 6:
        print("She")
    else:
        print("Vale isikukood")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the input as a string. Then get the first number of that input like this isikukood[:1]. As the first number is now a string (not integer) you should compare it with a string.

```
print("Sisesta isikukood")
isikukood = str(input())

if (isikukood[:1] == '1' or isikukood[:1] == '3' or isikukood[:1] == '5'):
    print("He")
elif isikukood[:1] == '2' or isikukood[:1]== '4' or isikukood[:1] == '6':
    print("She")
else:
    print("Vale isikukood")
```

Edu :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of convert the string (the value returned by `input()`), leave it as a string. And you can use index operator to get the first character:

```
print("Sisesta isikukood")
num = input()  # no `int(..)`

if num[:1] in ('1', '3', '5'):
    print("He")
elif num[:1] in ('2', '4', '6'):
    print("She")
else:
    print("Vale isikukood")
```

NOTE: The characters should be compared with characters. (`'1', '3', '5', ...` instead of `1, 3, 5`)

Comment: yeah , but well when i put more than 1 number it says  last els now.

Comment: @Martin, more than 1 number? What do you mean?

Comment: example when i put 2456 it says last els, as now it just reads only 1 charterer

Comment: @Martin, Ah sorry. I forget slicing(`[:1]`) after `num`. I just udpated the code in the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Oh thanks , but could u bite explain why [:1] not [0], Thanks! ))

Comment: @Martin, If use does not input anything `input()` will return empty string. Indexing on the empty string will raise `IndexError`. `[:1]` will return an empty string instead of raising the exception.